# Generating and accessing stored procedures using Entity framework core

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am implementing Asp.Net core Web API , entity framework core, database first approach using Visual Studio 2017. I have managed to generate the context and class files based on an existing database. I need to access stored procedures using my context. In earlier version of entity framework it was simple by selecting the stored procedure objects in the wizard and generating an edmx that contains those objects. I could then access stored procedures via the complex type objects exposed by entity framework. How do I do a similar thing in entity framework core. An example would help ?

Comment: You can use ADO.NET for your DbContext

Comment: An example would be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run stored procedures in Entity Framework Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599404/how-to-run-stored-procedures-in-entity-framework-core)

Comment: Line 227 https://github.com/hherzl/CatFactory.SqlServer/blob/master/src/CatFactory.SqlServer/SqlServerDatabaseFactory.cs This is helpful ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Database first approach is not there in EF Core with edmx files.Instead you have to use Scaffold-DbContext

Install  Nuget packages Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

but that will not get your stored procedures. It is still in the works,tracking issue [#245](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/245)

But, To execute the stored procedures, use [FromSql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) method which executes RAW SQL queries

e.g.

```
var products= context.Products
    .FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.GetProducts")
    .ToList();
```

To use with parameters

```
var productCategory= "Electronics";

var product = context.Products
    .FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.GetProductByCategory {0}", productCategory)
    .ToList();
```

or

```
var productCategory= new SqlParameter("productCategory", "Electronics");

var product = context.Product
    .FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.GetProductByName  @productCategory", productCategory)
    .ToList();
```

There are certain limitations to execute RAW SQL queries or stored procedures.You can’t use it for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE. if you want to execute INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE queries, use the ExecuteSqlCommand

```
var categoryName = "Electronics";
dataContext.Database
           .ExecuteSqlCommand("dbo.InsertCategory @p0", categoryName);
```

Comment: I get the following error after running the Scaffold-DbContext  System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: contentRootPath

Comment: I installed the packages but no `FromSql` is available. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 13):

The above examples work fine when executing a Stored Procedure if you are expecting the result set to be the same as any object already defined. But what if you want a resultset that is not supported? According to the developers of EF Core 2, this is a feature that will come, but there is already today an easy solution.

Create the model you want to use for your output. This model will represent the output, not a table in the database.

```
namespace Example.EF.Model
{
    public class Sample
    {
        public int SampleID { get; set; }
        public string SampleName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then add to your context a new DBSet with your model:

```
public virtual DbSet<Sample> Sample { get; set; }
```

And then do as above, and use your model for the output:

```
var products = _samplecontext.Sample
      .FromSql($"EXEC ReturnAllSamples {id}, {startdate}, {enddate}").ToList();
```

I hope this helps anyone out.

Comment: So doing this way, whenever we generate models using EF then we need to add manually the dbset everytime?

Comment: You can have them in a different file with partial class, to make it easier.

Comment: Hey @Sami , could you provide the partial class example please?

Comment: `EXEC ReturnAllSamples {id}, {startdate}, {enddate}` will generate sql without parameters and can be subject to SQL injection. .NET Core gives a very thorough warning message when you try to execute your procedure in this way. It's best to use the way the accepted answer is `.FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.GetProductByCategory {0}", productCategory)`

Comment: @SantiagoTrejo, I think what he means is you can create a partial of your DbContext (they generate as partials) and add your DbSet<> there. That way, if you regenerate your context, you won't lose the partial.

Answer (score 6):

My original post - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57224037/1979465

To call a stored procedure and get the result into a list of model in EF Core, we have to follow 3 steps.

**Step 1.**
You need to add a new class just like your entity class. Which should have properties with all the columns in your SP. For example if your SP is returning two columns called `Id` and `Name` then your new class should be something like

```
public class MySPModel
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

**Step 2.**

Then you have to add one `DbQuery` property into your DBContext class for your SP.

```
public partial class Sonar_Health_AppointmentsContext : DbContext
{
        public virtual DbSet<Booking> Booking { get; set; } // your existing DbSets
        ...

        public virtual DbQuery<MySPModel> MySP { get; set; } // your new DbQuery
        ...
}
```

**Step 3.**

Now you will be able to call and get the result from your SP from your DBContext.

```
var result = await _context.Query<MySPModel>()
    .AsNoTracking()
    .FromSql(string.Format("EXEC {0} {1}", functionName, parameter))
    .ToListAsync();
```

I am using a generic UnitOfWork & Repository. So my function to execute the SP is

```
/// <summary>
/// Execute function. Be extra care when using this function as there is a risk for SQL injection
/// </summary>
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> ExecuteFuntion<T>(string functionName, string parameter) where T : class
{
    return await _context.Query<T>()
        .AsNoTracking()
        .FromSql(string.Format("EXEC {0} {1}", functionName, parameter)).ToListAsync();
}
```

Hope it will be helpful for someone !!!

Answer (score 3):

The workaround we use in EF Core to execute stored procedures to get the data is by using FromSql method and you can execute stored procedure this way:

```
List<Employee> employees = dbcontext.Employee
                    .FromSql("GetAllEmployees").ToList();
```

But for Create, Update, and Delete, we use ExecuteSqlCommand like the one below:

```
var employee = "Harold Javier";
dbcontext.Employee
           .ExecuteSqlCommand("InsertEmployee @emp", employee);
```

Comment: in case the SP is returning the value from multiple tables using join , then this will fail , what approach we should use

Answer (score 1):

The solution Rohith / Harold Javier / Sami provided works. I would like to add that you can create a separate EF6 project to generate the C# classes for resultsets and then copy the files to your EFCore project. If you change a stored proc, you can update the result file using the methods discussed here: [Stored Procedures and updating EDMX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18038405/stored-procedures-and-updating-edmx)

If you need corresponding typescript interfaces, you can install this VS2017 extension typescript definition generator: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.TypeScriptDefinitionGenerator

There are still be a couple of copying, but it is less tedious than creating the classes manually.

Edit: there is a VS2017 extension for generating the dbconext https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EFCorePowerTools. It does not do stored procedures, but it provides a right click menu item from VS project instead of the command line Scaffold-DbContext.

Comment: EF6 would be the way to go then. Until ef core will have stored procedure support.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to execute stored procedure in MySQL database from EntityFramework Core, the following code should work.

```
var blogTagId = 1;
var tags = await _dbContext.BlogTags.FromSqlRaw("CALL SP_GetBlogTags({0})", blogTagId).ToListAsync();
```