# Why my complex types is not updated when i add a stored procedure into edmx in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using the Entity Framework to create a complex types from some stored procedures. Now, I changed one of the stored procedure to display 2 more fields.

I'm trying to update the complex type that maps to this stored procedure, but it's not working!  Also, I tried both approaches:

1. Delete all 3 parts in model, and add again
2. Update the Model from the database and then update function imports

but they did not work!

Also, in the first way, when I add the stored procedure to the model, the complex type isn't updated. Besides, in the second way, when I "Edit Function Imports" and "Get Column Information", I get a message

> The selected stored procedure or function returns no columns

while it's returning about 30 columns through a select statement!

The last part of my stored procedure is like this:

```
select * 
from MyTable  
where Name like '%My Name%'
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem happened with me when I update the EDMX from existing database, but I solve it through:

1. Check the output of stored procedure in your database.
2. Do this steps:

   - Delete the EDMX.
   - Delete the connection string in app.config , save app.config and close app.config.
   - Clean the project.
   - Add EDMX again.
   - Rebuild the project.

hope this fix the problem.

Comment: But this project is a big one with about 27 SPs which are working now. It's a risky way since I cannot update only one; so, how about those 27??? also, i don't think this is a good approach to apply each changes in SPs.

Comment: Yes it is, but look at this question [Stored Procedures and updating EDMX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18038405/stored-procedures-and-updating-edmx) hope fix your problem